# CSS Gradient Overlay Click-Through Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm using this jQuery library to help stream a bunch of logos: [SmoothDivScroll](http://smoothdivscroll.com/)

Got it working great and I love it.

But I wanted to add just one more thing. I want a gradient overlay over the scroller so that on each side of the scroller the logos transition from white -> opaque -> white by the time it scrolls to the other side.

Something similar to this site: http://creativehero.es/

I got it working with the following code EXCEPT it kills my hyperlinks for each logo. I've tried messing around with pointer-events/z-index and I just can't get the overlay on top of the scroller and also have the logos in the scroller clickable. It's also always the same behavior across all modern browsers. Here's the CSS:

```
/* The scroll wrapper is always the same width and height as the containing element (div).
   Overflow is hidden because you don't want to show all of the scrollable area.
*/
div.scrollWrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
    pointer-events: visible;

}

div.scrollableArea
{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: visible;

}


#logoParade
{
    width: auto;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative; 
    pointer-events: visible;    
}

#logoParade a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    pointer-events: visible;
    z-index:210;
}

#logoParade img 
{       
    height:65px;
    width:auto; 
    pointer-events: visible;
}

#logoParade img:hover {
-ms-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: scale(1.03,1.03);    
}



.grad {
pointer-events: none;
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(1%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(20%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(80%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
```

And here's the html:

```
<div class="row grad" >
            <div id="logoParade">
                <div class="scrollWrapper">
                    <div class="scrollableArea" style="width: 6000px;">


@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@*
Macro Parameters To Create, for this macro to work:
Show:True   Alias:mediaId     Name:Media Folder ID    Type:MediaCurrent
*@


@if (Parameter.mediaId == null)
{
     @* Get the media folder as a dynamic node *@
    var mediaFolder =  Library.MediaById(5093);

    if (mediaFolder.Children.Any())
    {

            @* for each item in children of the selected media folder *@
            foreach (var mediaItem in mediaFolder.Children)
            {

                <a href="@mediaItem.website" target="_blank"><img  src="@mediaItem.umbracoFile" alt="@mediaItem.Name" /></a>

            }

    }
}


    </div>
        </div>
         </div>    
        </div>
```

I also want to add that adding z-index:-1 to either div element (scrollWrapper or scrollableArea) brings the gradient out in front of the scroller, but that is also the culprit not allowing my anchor tags to be clicked.

Comment: The particular site you linked to provides one possible solution. The gradient is attached to an element which only takes up as much room as the gradient. You still wouldn't be able to click through the gradient area though, but that site makes use of the gradient by making it act to speed up the scrolling when clicked, and the appropriate gradient is hidden when the scroller reaches the end of its travel.

Comment: I'm actually going to try implementing what that site did I suppose. They're using an image for the gradient instead of drawing it. I just wanted to take the hard way out and try doing it with just CSS and allow the gradient to be click-throughable. Thanks!

Comment: It might also be useful to know what browsers you are testing on and need to support. According to MDN, your use of pointer-events should work, but IE < 11 doesn't support it, and I expect earlier versions of other browsers probably don't either.

Comment: Chrome 33, I.E. 10, ff 27

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events. IE 10 shouldn't work, but I don't see why that wouldn't work on Chrome 33 or FF 27.